# Npm not responding for changes in a .jsx file after saving it

Tags: reactjs, npm, save, jsx, npm-start

I am trying to save the changes in a file named Comments.jsx but npm is not responding to that changes even I am making errors but for other files it is working properly.

[As you can see even there is error in Commets.jsx file but npm not responding to it even I saved it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjkZl.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I check your image found that wrong syntax in image at line 8.

[Find Attached image for solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUqt9.png)

Your can try as below:

[styled syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFMTU.png)

Comment: I am not having a problem with the error I am facing a problem in saving the changes npm is not responding to the changes at all in this file.